# SQL: Column is ambigious

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have the following SQL query, which has a subquery in it:

```
SELECT * FROM `statics` WHERE `mmsi`= 
(SELECT `mmsi` FROM `positions`,`active` 
WHERE `active.mmsi` = `positions.position_ID`);
```

But when I execute it, I get the following error:

> ## 1052 - Column 'mmsi' in field list is ambiguous

Please help me on adjusting my query.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your table structure, this is a wild guess:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `statics` 
WHERE `statics.mmsi` = (SELECT `active.mmsi` 
                        FROM `positions`,`active` 
                        WHERE `active.mmsi` = `positions.position_ID`);
```

but I don't get why are you doing this with a subquery. This one should yield the same results

```
SELECT statics.* 
FROM `statics`, `positions`
WHERE `statics.mmsi` = `positions.position_ID`;
```

Comment: Well I have data in my statics table, which contains a mmsi column which has a value of lets say 5. Around this, is a subquery (which works normally for me) which checks and gets the mmsi from two other tables (active & positions). So those two tables compare a mmsi and then set it. Then the statics table as last will select it and also compare it to show its values.

Comment: This is what I would guess also, but for an explanation, the `mmsi` column in the sub-query likely exists in both the `positions` and `active` table.